# rollback column to which it was updated without where in oracle database

Tags: oracle, rollback

Good morning, during an execution of an SQL query in an Oracle database, perform an UPDATE without using the where and update an entire column unintentionally, now I want to retrieve it by rollback, the question is how to make an update to update my column current with which I am recovering.
To retrieve my column you are using the following query:

```
select CONTENT  
 from ACTION as of timestamp 
      to_timestamp('21-NOV-2019 11:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Now I want the response of this query to serve as an argument to update (UPDATE) the entire CONTENT column of my ACTION table; as it was at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple update statement. I am considering that you only need to update the column value to the past value but all other data needs to be untouched.

```
Update action a
Set a.content = (select * from (select b.CONTENT from ACTION b 
Where b.primarykey_colum = a.primarykey_colum) as of timestamp to_timestamp('21-NOV-2019 11:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

If you want to flashback entire table then use following:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE action 
  TO TIMESTAMP to_timestamp('21-NOV-2019 11:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Cheers!!

Comment: With the query of just updating the CONTENT column, I get the following error: ORA-00907: missing the right parenthesis. I am using SQL Developer

Comment: In the flashback I get the following error: ORA-08189: the flashback row movement cannot be enabled; How could I do to enable column movement? Thank you to see if it works out there, since it is giving me trouble with the individual consultation